# I am getting the No line error again and again

Tags: java

I have just started java, and am still a rookie. I am getting an error as soon as I create a second object in my code, or even if I use the getdata() method twice. So there's something wrong in the getdata() method. I am not able to understand what.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
Though the code works till the print statement for a.name is executed but it throws the error as soon as the object b is created.

I have given more inputs than required, considering that the error is demanding an input.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class jatt
{ 

    String name;

    String DOB;

    String BG;

    int BP;

    int TeleNumber;

    int DrivNumber;

    String address;

    void getdata(){
        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
        name=in.nextLine();
        DOB=in.nextLine();
        BG=in.nextLine();
        BP=in.nextInt();
        TeleNumber=in.nextInt();
        DrivNumber=in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        address=in.nextLine();
    }
    jatt(){
        getdata();
    }
    jatt(String name, String DOB ,String BG, int BP, int TeleNumber, int DrivNumber, String address){
        this.name=name;
        this.DOB=DOB;
        this.BG=BG;
        this.BP=BP;
        this.TeleNumber=TeleNumber;
        this.DrivNumber=DrivNumber;
        this.address=address;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
        jatt a= new jatt();
        System.out.println(a.name);
        jatt b= new jatt();
        System.out.println(b.name);
    }
}
```

The error comes only when the second object is created, the code works fine for a single object. And I know about the problem of using in.nextLine() just after in.nextInt(). So the error is somewhere else.

Comment: What input did you give ? Can you please post that.

Comment: 1
2
3
4
5
6
7
1
2
3
4
45
5
6
7
4
2
4
45
3 I specifically gave more inputs than required, so that the no line error can be eliminated.

Comment: Everything seems to work fine for me. Did you press enter after each number or did you type the whole input and then pressed enter?

Comment: Your variables are not following the [Java's naming convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html); Your `DOB`, `BG` and `BP` variables are not starting with a lowercase, and aren't mnemonic (mnemonic = designed to indicate intent to any casual observer). --- The `getData()` method has an empty `in.nextLine();` that is not doing anything. --- You don't need to throw unspecified exceptions at main; they will get thrown anyway, if they aren't caught within or before reaching main.

Comment: In my tests of your code, scanner seems to skip the address for some reason. This may be a Java bug (???)